# How to Create a network connection between host and guest using static ip in Oracle Virtual Box

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, scientific-linux

In host I am using `Scientific Linux 6.4`

In guest I am using `CentOS 6.4`

Oracle Virtual Box Version 4.2.18 r88780

I want a create a network between host and guest machine using **static ip** so in Virtual Box I selected [Host-only](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly) Adapter

[image]

In base system it created a new interface called `vboxnet0`

```
vboxnet0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0A:00:27:00:00:00  
          inet addr:192.168.56.1  Bcast:192.168.56.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::800:27ff:fe00:0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:468 (468.0 b)
```

After starting guest os I tried ping command to ping my host machine, it was not pinging, this is the output.

```
[root@localhost ~]# ping 192.168.56.1
PING 192.168.56.1 (192.168.56.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.56.2 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.56.2 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.56.2 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 192.168.56.1 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 4658ms
pipe 3
```

In guest machine for which interface I should set static ip ? for eth0 I set the static ip ie; 192.168.56.3 still it's not pinging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution.

While typing `ifconfig eth0` it was showing the ip address.

```
[root@localhost ~]# ifconfig eth0
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1E:EC:95:18:66  
          inet addr:192.168.56.7  Bcast:192.168.56.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
          Interrupt:19
```

In `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` file also it was showing ip address.

```
.
.
IPADDR=192.168.56.7
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
.
.
```

Even it was pinging the ip also.

```
[root@localhost ~]# ping 192.168.56.7
PING 192.168.56.7 (192.168.56.7) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.56.7: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.098 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.56.7: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.080 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.56.7: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.087 ms
^C
--- 192.168.56.7 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2032ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.080/0.088/0.098/0.010 ms
```

Here I got confused, I thought that it's pinging right then my `eth0` interface is working. This is the main mistake I did.

Today I tried this command

```
[root@localhost ~]# /etc/init.d/network restart
Shutting down interface eth0:  Error: Device 'eth0' (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/0) disconnecting failed: This device is not active
                                                           [FAILED]
Shutting down loopback interface:                          [  OK  ]
Bringing up loopback interface:                            [  OK  ]
Bringing up interface eth0:  RTNETLINK answers: File exists
```

It was showing this **This device is not active** . Then I got the reason why its not working. After that I edited `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` file with only this content and deleted all the other lines.

```
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=none
HWADDR=AA:BB:BB:DD:EE:FF
NM_CONTROLLED=no
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=192.168.56.7
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
```

After that I restated the network service, tried ping command and its started to ping my guest machine that is 192.168.56.9.

Answer (score 0):

Clicking to the `Cable connected` check-box would be a good start for communication to occur between your guest and host.

Comment: After enabling `Cable connected` also its not working.