# VirtualBox Networking does not work on Linux host?

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, fedora

My host OS is Fedora 18 (kernel: 3.11.10) and I am running VirtualBox 4.2.18. The only networking mode which is working is NAT and non of Bridged Adapter, Internal, and Host-Only works! By this, I mean when I start a virtual machine, I can't get an IP and ping my virtual machine. I really have no idea why this behaves like this since it was working previously without any problem. Any idea please?

Comment: While typing /etc/init.d/network restart are you getting any error message?

Comment: Ok then follow this link,  I am not sure whether it will help you or not http://superuser.com/questions/655331/how-to-create-a-network-connection-between-host-and-guest-using-static-ip-in-ora

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work too!